# Problem with date calendar

Tags: visualforce, calendar

i am showing my date field value in input field in page block section as follows.   but calendar is not rendering when i click on this field.
please suggest aomething.
Thanks in advance.

```
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Date"/>
                    <apex:inputField required="{!OR(f.required,f.dbrequired)}" value=" {!details[f]}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably set `standardStylesheets` properties to `false` in apex:page element. 
like below :-

```
<apex:page id="page" controller="ApplicationInfoController"     
   tabstyle="Application_Info__tab"  standardStylesheets="false" 
      title="APPLICATION INFORMATION">
```

remove this from here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using field sets to render the page. Please check if you have added your date field in the field sets.

Comment: yes i have added the field.it is showing also but problem is calendar which is by default associated with date field in salesforce is not showing

Comment: I tried a simple example, and it worked fine for me. If you coud paste your code, may be it will be easy to identify. Adding my code below.

Comment: TypeError: a is null
https://cp8.visual.force.com/jslibrary/1458245875/sfdc/main.js
Line 86 I am getting this javascript error.